# Draw several rectangles inside one UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a task to implement the following view:

[image]

I decided to do that using custom UIView with drawing rects. I was able to draw four rects using UIBezierPath:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        UIColor.systemGray.setFill()
        path.fill()
        
        let offset: CGFloat = 4.0
        
        let firstRect = UIBezierPath()
        firstRect.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + offset, y: bounds.origin.y + offset))
        firstRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2.0, y: bounds.origin.y + offset))
        firstRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2.0, y: bounds.height / 2.0))
        firstRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + offset, y: bounds.height / 2.0))
        firstRect.close()
        
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        firstRect.stroke()
        firstRect.fill()
        
        let secondRect = UIBezierPath()
        secondRect.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2 + offset, y: bounds.origin.y + offset))
        secondRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - offset, y: bounds.origin.y + offset))
        secondRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - offset, y: bounds.height / 2.0))
        secondRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2 + offset, y: bounds.height / 2.0))
        secondRect.close()
        
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        secondRect.stroke()
        secondRect.fill()
        
        let thirdRect = UIBezierPath()
        thirdRect.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + offset, y: bounds.height / 2 + offset))
        thirdRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2.0, y: bounds.height / 2 + offset))
        thirdRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2.0, y: bounds.height - offset))
        thirdRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + offset, y: bounds.height - offset))
        thirdRect.close()
        
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        thirdRect.stroke()
        thirdRect.fill()
        
        let fourthRect = UIBezierPath()
        fourthRect.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2 + offset, y: bounds.height / 2 + offset))
        fourthRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - offset, y: bounds.height / 2 + offset))
        fourthRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - offset, y: bounds.height - offset))
        fourthRect.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2 + offset, y: bounds.height - offset))
        fourthRect.close()
        
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        fourthRect.stroke()
        fourthRect.fill()
    }
```

I'm trying to write a method that will take a certain amount of rects and draw them. The issue is that there may be an arbitrary number of rects (not only four as I did above) and I can't seem to figure out how to properly place them without saying that, for example, one rect should originate in the upper left corner, another right below it, etc. In fact, it should more or less look like a collection view but a collection view doesn't exactly fit my needs.

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: I actually have three or four apps in the Store that depend entirely upon doing just the sort of thing you describe. Think about the notion of a grid and the xy coordinates of one piece within the grid.

Comment: why didn't you use `collectionView`?

Comment: @えるまる I had to implement zooming behavior, talked about that with our senior dev, ended up agreeing that implementing zooming behavoir with a custom view will be easier.

Comment: @matt You are the keeper, mate, thanks a ton for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is about as basic as life gets. Simply think about the notion of a *grid* and the xy coordinates of one piece within the grid. Now you know where to place each subview.

Here, to show you the general idea, is a simplified version of what you're doing. Imagine that we have no blank areas: just a solid grid of squares that are either red or gray. And let's imagine that this grid is 12x8.

So to start with, how would we just construct a 12x8 grid of gray squares? In your code, you are doing it with actual drawing, in `draw(_:)`; my approach uses subviews (and sublayers is also a possibility, if you think subviews is too much overhead), but the underlying principle is *exactly* the same:

```
// assume 12x8 squares
let xmax = 12, ymax = 8
let w = self.view.bounds.width / CGFloat(xmax)
for i in 0..<xmax {
    for j in 0..<ymax {
        let rect = CGRect(x: w*CGFloat(i), y: w*CGFloat(j), width: w, height: w).insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)
        let v = UIView(frame:rect)
        // v.backgroundColor = withRedOnes.contains([i,j]) ? .red : .gray
        v.backgroundColor = .gray
        self.view.addSubview(v)
    }
}
```

[image]

Do you see the key concept? `i` and `j` are the *grid* placement of a square. From that, we can easily calculate the `rect` where that square goes. That's all there is to it!

Now specifying that something *different*, like a red view, goes at any particular coordinate, is trivial:

```
func makeGrid(withRedOnes: [[Int]]) {
    // assume 12x8 squares
    let xmax = 12, ymax = 8
    let w = self.view.bounds.width / CGFloat(xmax)
    for i in 0..<xmax {
        for j in 0..<ymax {
            let rect = CGRect(x: w*CGFloat(i), y: w*CGFloat(j), width: w, height: w).insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)
            let v = UIView(frame:rect)
            v.backgroundColor = withRedOnes.contains([i,j]) ? .red : .gray
            self.view.addSubview(v)
        }
    }
}
```

If we call that method like this:

```
self.makeGrid(withRedOnes:[[6,3], [7,3]])
```

Then we get this:

[image]

Okay, now. In real life, you're not doing to use a mere UIView as each square. You will have your own UIView subclass that knows how to draw itself: with a color, with a number, whataever. And you won't reconstruct *all* the views every time something changes; you will just change that *one* view within the grid, removing it or placing it, changing the way it draws itself, whatever.

As practice, I suggest you try writing a simpler grid-based app, such as a tic-tac-toe game (3x3 grid of "O" and "X"). Once you have that down, you will just tweak it successively to do all sorts of fancy things, like offsetting or centering a row of the grid and other requirements you may have in order to "draw" a theatre layout.

Comment: I actually have at least _four_ App Store apps that follow this same basic principle of laying out a grid of subview / sublayers: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/diabellis-theme/id634208794, https://apps.apple.com/us/app/zotz/id346433833, https://apps.apple.com/us/app/99-bottles/id346204860, https://apps.apple.com/us/app/linksame/id387799116/. Download any of them and think about how it's done. None of those is a collection view; they are all grids of the type I've described in my answer, though of course using far more object-oriented principles in the detailed programming.